# Create Azure AD group with Group.Create Permission

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an Azure AD Group via the Graph API using a service principal. The intent is that the service principal will create the group in a Pipelines run.

The call I am using to attempt to create the group is

```
az rest --method post \
  --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' \
  --body '{"description": "A description", "displayName": "MyAppGroup", "mailEnabled": false, "mailNickname": "test", "securityEnabled": true, "owners@odata.bind": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/oooooooo-oooo-oooo-oooo-oooooooooooo"]}' \
  --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

To graph permissions, I have bound the API permission `Group.Create` to my service principal. To understand the permissions I am required to grant, I am following this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

With the `Group.Create` permissions, when I run the rest call to the Graph API above, I get the following permission error

```
Forbidden({
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-02T13:31:35",
      "request-id": "...",
      "client-request-id": "..."
    }
  }
})
```

I completely understand that if I were to add the `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, I could make the group and would have all required permissions. However this permission is overscoped and would allow my service principal to disable users in the Active Directory tenant - something my organisation will now allow. Therefore I cannot grant my service principal this permission.

The documentation I have linked above implies to me that `Group.Create` is a sufficient permission to enable a service principal to create a group.

My question is what I am doing wrong, or what permissions am I missing to be able to create a group? `Directory.ReadWrite.All` is clearly overscoped to simply create an AD security group and so using it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone else - I realised the answer immediately after posting this.

I had added the property

```
"owners@odata.bind": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/oooooooo-oooo-oooo-oooo-oooooooooooo"]
```

to the `json` post data.

Removing this property allowed me to create the group with just the `Group.Create` permission.

Adding the permission `User.Read.All` allows the service principal to read the user data for the owner, and so is sufficient to create the group with any necessary owners.

After adding this API permission, my service principal was able to create the group (with owners) as expected.